# Numpy: Efficient access to sub-arrays generated by numpy.split

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, arraylist

I have the following code that generates a list of sub-arrays based on the split function. Here, I just compare the first value of each tuple and based on the difference I generate the sub-arrays. So far so good.

```
import numpy as np

f = np.genfromtxt("d_n_isogro_ms.txt", names=True, dtype=None, usecols=(1,-1))

dm  = np.absolute(np.diff(f['mz']))
pos = np.where(dm > 2)[0] + 1
fsplit = np.array_split(f, pos)
```

This is how the sample input looks like (only an excerpt):

```
[(270.0332, 472) (271.0376, 1936) (272.0443, 11188) (273.0495, 65874)
 (274.0517, 8582) (275.0485, 4081) (276.0523, 659) (286.058, 1078)
 (287.0624, 4927) (288.0696, 22481) (289.0757, 84001) (290.078, 13688)
 (291.0746, 5402) (430.1533, 13995) (431.1577, 2992) (432.1685, 504)]
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

The position for this particular data is then computed as:

```
pos = [7,12]
```

And here is my sample output:

```
[array([(270.0332, 472), (271.0376, 1936), (272.0443, 11188),
       (273.0495, 65874), (274.0517, 8582), (275.0485, 4081),
       (276.0523, 659)], dtype=[('mz', '<f8'), ('I', '<i8')]),
array([(286.058, 1078), (287.0624, 4927), (288.0696, 22481),
   (289.0757, 84001), (290.078, 13688), (291.0746, 5402)], 
  dtype=[('mz', '<f8'), ('I', '<i8')]),
array([(430.1533, 13995),
   (431.1577, 2992), (432.1685, 504)], 
  dtype=[('mz', '<f8'), ('I', '<i8')])]
```

I would like to perform the weighted average on each of the arrays. Is there an efficient way of doing this with numpy? I basically fail with the indexing. Preferably, I would like to use the dtype to identify weights and numbers.

Maybe one could do the whole operation on the fly

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Best,
Christian

Comment: Sample input, output as [`mcve`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might help us help you.

Comment: Thank. Sorry I totally forgot.

Comment: Do you have a corresponding `pos` as well for the sample input, output that you just posted? `pos` could be useful I think.

Comment: `pos` might be `[7,13]` instead for `np.array_split(f, pos)` to give the expected output? Also, as the final output, you are looking to have weighted average, right? So, what must that be for given sample inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `np.array_split` is a Python list containing arrays of unequal lenghts. The best you can do in that case is a Python loop:

```
result = [np.average(f_i['mz'], weights=f_i['I']) for f_i in fsplit]
```

But it is possible to come up with a completely vectorized solution, by using `add.reduceat` instead of `array_split`:

```
dm = np.abs(np.diff(f['mz']))
pos = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True, dm > 2])

totals = np.add.reduceat(f['mz']*f['I'], pos)
counts = np.add.reduceat(f['I'], pos)
result = totals / counts
```

Comment: Thank you very much. First of, it works. Second I like the vectorized solution and will use it for future scripts.